# FASTCV linking error with Visual Studio 2013 for Windows mobile

Tags: linker, fastcv

I'm trying to link FastCV with Windows runtime project on Visual Studio 2013. I'm getting the following error.

> LNK2038: mismatch detected for '_MSC_VER': value '1800' doesn't match value '1700' .

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1800 --> Visual Studio 2013

1700 --> Visual Studio 2013

This means that you use a dependency (probably a `.dll` file) that is intended for Visual Studio 2012. Revise your dependencies, and make sure they are all compatible with VS 2013, or switch to VS 2012 (uninstall 2013 first then install 2012).